# Rcpp: Constructing templated functions

Tags: c++, rcpp

I have the following MWE. It contains a class with two members, an integer and a string. Using the function `first` I create an object of the class and return a pointer to it. In `second_int` and `second_str` I output the two members.

Given that `second_int` and `second_str` have more or less the same function, it seems obvious to me to template them. Is this possible to do within Rcpp given my MWE?

```
class C{
public:
  std::vector<int> i_vec;
  std::vector<std::string> s_vec;

  C(){
    i_vec.push_back(0);
    s_vec.push_back("R");
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<C> first()
{
  XPtr<C> p(new C, true);
  return(p);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void second_int(XPtr<C> p)
{
  Rcout << p->i_vec[0] << "\n";
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void second_str(XPtr<C> p)
{
  Rcout << p->s_vec[0] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The functions make look similar...from the outside, but internally they are doing two very different things. Any attempt to merge these into one function is sure to turn out badly. I suggest you either leave them the way they are, or parameterize the functions on the vector types they operate on; i.e. pass in a vector not a pointer to C

Comment: Why do you want to template them. Their inputs/outputs are identical: `void` and `XPtr`. They are two different functions. This code sounds correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templating can not be used directly here, but we can use it to accomplish what I think you want! Let's consider what you've got written and what it appears you would *like* to write directly.

You have:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void second_int(XPtr<C> p)
{
  Rcout << p->i_vec[0] << "\n";
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void second_str(XPtr<C> p)
{
  Rcout << p->s_vec[0] << "\n";
}
```

and what you would like (this is not valid C++) is this:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
template< membername member_to_extract >
void second(XPtr<C> p)
{
  Rcout << p->member_to_extract[0] << "\n";
}

/**
 * we would like to call it like this:
 * second<i_vec>(p) (to get the int value)
 * second<s_vec>(p) (to get the str value)
 */
```

Why doesn't this work? Well, checking http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters, we see that you can't pass variable names in as template parameters! So this approach is doomed to fail. (NOTE: You *can* use macros for this, which may be the solution you're looking for!)

However, while your functions arguments and return types are the same, their behavior *is* decided solely based on the type you want to work with. If you are going to be using these functions in an already templated context, then it would be desirable to get second and second interfaces!

Template specialization to the rescue!

```
// generic template. We need something that fails to compile
// so that second<int> and second<std::string> are the only
// specializations the compiler will allow us to use.
template< typename T >
void second(XPtr<C> p)
{
  static_assert(false, "second can't be used with this type.");
}

template< >
void second<int>(XPtr<C> p)
{
  Rcout << p->i_vec[0] << "\n";
}

template< >
void second<std::string>(XPtr<C> p)
{
  Rcout << p->s_vec[0] << "\n";
}
```

I think this is what you want? Note that if your platform is not line-buffered you probably want to use std::endl instead of "\n", as it forces a flush (which is probably the behavior you want).

EDIT: Partial specialization -> template specialization